# Javascript object Class is not defined Error

Tags: javascript, php, function-prototypes

I have a mainoops.js file which has following code

```
var Notifier = function(){

    this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    this.currentdate = new Date();


}

 Notifier.prototype.addCbNotification  = function(message){

    var datetime = this.currentdate.getDate() + "/" + (this.currentdate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + this.currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ " + currentdate.getHours() + ":" + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds();

     var  datamessage = " <div class='row'><div class='col-xs-2'><i class='fa fa-envelope'></i></div><div class='col-xs-10'><h5><a href=''>" + message + "</a></h5><small>"+datetime+"</small></div></div>";

    $("#callback-btn").addClass('alert-notice');
    $( "#callback" ).append( "<li class='list-group-item unread'>"+datamessage+" </li> " );

}

Notifier.prototype.addNotification  = function(message){

    var datetime = currentdate.getDate() + "/" + (currentdate.getMonth()+1) + "/" + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ " + currentdate.getHours() + ":" + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds();

     var  datamessage = " <div class='row'><div class='col-xs-2'><i class='fa fa-envelope'></i></div><div class='col-xs-10'><h5><a href=''>" + message + "</a></h5><small>"+datetime+"</small></div></div>";

    $("#notice-btn").addClass('alert-notice');
    $( "#notice" ).append( "<li class='list-group-item unread'>"+datamessage+" </li> " );

}

Notifier.prototype.startsocketforcallbback = function(myid) {
    // body...

    socket.on('callback', function (data) {
            var message = data.split("_"); 
            if(myid.toLowerCase().trim() == message[0].toLowerCase().trim()){
              this.addCbNotification(message[1]);
          }
          });
};

Notifier.prototype.startsocketfornotice = function() {
    // body...

    socket.on('notice', function (data) {
            var message = data.split("_"); 
            if(myid.toLowerCase().trim() == message[0].toLowerCase().trim()){
              this.addNotification(message[1]);
          }
          });
};
```

I am calling it in my php file as follow

```
<script src="{{asset('/js/mainoops.js')}}"></script>
```

But when I try to instantiate it in the PHP page like this

```
<script>
    var obj = new Notifier();
        obj.startsocketforcallbback('<?php echo Auth::user()->empid; ?>');
        obj.startsocketfornotice();
</script>
```

I am getting following **ERROR**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Notifier is not defined
```

Comment: Please give the reason for Down Voting thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, but `this` is your callbacks did not points to your Notifier instance. Try to use 3rd parameter of `on(..)`:

```
socket.on('callback', function (data) {
        var message = data.split("_"); 
        if(myid.toLowerCase().trim() == message[0].toLowerCase().trim()){
          this.addCbNotification(message[1]);
      }
      },this);
```

in `Notifier.prototype.startsocketforcallbback` and

```
socket.on('notice', function (data) {
            var message = data.split("_"); 
            if(myid.toLowerCase().trim() == message[0].toLowerCase().trim()){
              this.addNotification(message[1]);
          }
          },this);
```

in `Notifier.prototype.startsocketfornotice`

Comment: I did not get  it should I update `this` in the socket? I tried that but it does not work

Comment: In javascript `this` is not a pointer to your object instance as in Java or any other language. `this` means (it is very far analogy) execution context for current method/function. So, when the socket calling your callback function it probably set the current context to null or window.
But, I'm afraid, this error (`Uncaught ReferenceError: Notifier`) means that the page did not load your `mainoops.js`, so it knows nothing about your Notifier. Try to use `Developer tools` in Chrome or "Developer" menu in Firefox to understand why browser did not load your js.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var obj = new Notifier();
        obj.startsocketforcallbback('<?php echo Auth::user()->empid; ?>');
        obj.startsocketfornotice();
});
```